# upgrade not allowed with locked packages?

Tags: upgrade

I've got 2 packages with the version locked because the new ones are not compatible with other programs I use.  This prevents the Ubuntu distribution upgrade from even trying to do its work. Observe:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unit193/encryption/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  git-lfs thunderbird
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

The only workaround I can see is to allow the updates to happen with git-lfs and thunderbird, then do the upgrade, and then install the old versions of those programs.  Seems more tedious than it should be.

Other ideas?

Comment: Other idea: Do not upgrade.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: smiley face.

Comment: Really, it's a LTS :)

Comment: Maybe that's right. Even after allowing it to update thunderbird and git-lfs, I end up in the well known hell about python versions.  Upgrader says "Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink."  There must be 100 user questions about that hassle.

Comment: You may want to try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, this should upgrade packages that have been kept back.

Comment: I don't have trouble updating the packages.  I just don't want to do it. Oh, well.